Tracking output of iterating $f(x) = \frac{x(x^3 - 16x)}{4(x^3 + 2)}$
Consider the function $e(x) = \frac{x}{4}$ Now let us apply it iteratively the output will be $\{\frac{x}{4}, \frac{x}{4^2}, \frac{x}{4^3}, …\}$ We notice that only the power of 4 are increasing so for $x = a$ we can define another function $e_r(x) = a\cdot4^{-x}$ (where $a \in \mathbb{R}$) Any input in $e_r(x)$ will give us the value of $e(a)$ iterated that number of time. I have derived this by analysing the function but not with a general method.
Now consider the rational function $f(x) = \frac{x(x^3 - 16x)}{4(x^3 + 2)}$ How can I calculate $f_r(x)$, similar to $e_r(x)$ above, that will give me value of $f$ applied, on $a$, $x$ times.
Since $f(x)$ is undefined at $x = (-7)^{1/3}$ and I do not need negative numbers we limit the domain to $\mathbb{R}_+$ (all non negative real numbers).
How can I find such a function? Or if it exists?
All I know is that most probably $f_r(x)$ will be something like $f_r(x) = a\cdot z \cdot 4^{-x}$ where $a$ will be the input on which $f$ will be iterated and $4^{-x}$ comes from $\frac{x}{4}$ and $z$ will be something remaining.
Any direction in which you can guide me?

You are looking at an iterated function; I don't see why one would believe that rational function has a closed form. In terms of directions to guide you, dynamics as a field... and maybe a term like Fatou (component, e.g.) as something worth reading about.

Your $f(x)-x$ is negative for positive reals, so however large an $x$ you start with, eventually $f_r(x)$ will reach a number less than $4$ and then turn negative.  So it will not exist for large enough $r$.  Even if it did, as mentioned above, there may not be a simple/explicit closed form.

@Macavity What purpose the nature of $f(x) - x$ serve here? $r$ is just used for iteration it will not have a value, I think you are mentioning about $a$ or number of time iteration needs to be done. My original problem isn't covered, however, in the question. Actually I am working in a Finite field. Should I add this to question or ask a new question?
